# Generics in record "with" syntax

Tags: f#, functor

If I've got a record with a generic field, is there any way to mimic the convenient `with` syntax when changing the generic?

i.e. if I have

```
type User<'photo> = // 'photo can be Bitmap or Url
  { first: string; last: string; address: string; phone: string; photo: 'photo }
```

I want to be able to write something like

```
let loadUser(user: User<Url>): User<Bitmap> =
  { user with
    photo = download user.photo }
```

But it looks like I've got to write this instead.

```
let loadUser(user: User<Url>): User<Bitmap> =
  { first = user.first
    last = user.last
    address = user.address
    phone = user.phone
    photo = download user.photo }
```

Is there a way to get the first syntax?

Comment: No chance of making photo `type Photo = Image of Bitmap | Location of Url`? Then `User` is a concrete type and `with` just works.

Comment: @Daniel yes, see my comment below Carsten's answer though.  Still that may be the best option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not directly but you can make your `User` into a *functor* (for the `photo` part):

```
let fmap (f : 'a -> 'b) (user: User<'a>): User<'b> =
  { first   = user.first
    last    = user.last
    address = user.address
    phone   = user.phone
    photo   = f user.photo }
```

once and write (for example):

```
let loadUser (user : User<Url>) : User<Bitmap> =
    fmap download user
```

also you could *rename* `fmap` into `withPhoto` if you prefer `let loadUser = withPhoto download` :D

now it might be a bit strange that the `photo` part is any kind of data/type so I would think about renamig this part just into `value` - but that's just me

Comment: Good point, maybe `photo` should be a DU and have a `getBitmap` function.  But then I lose compile-time guarantees that a bitmap is actually cached in memory.  So if I want that guarantee then have to make `User` generic again and I'm back in the same boat.

Comment: if it's just about making sure that a on-demand download is cached you can always use `Lazy<Bitmap>` - but I think that is another question ;)

Answer (score 4):

Sadly the `{ with .. }` syntax does not handle the case when the type changes (though I think this could be added, so feel free to open a suggestion at the F# user voice page!)

Adding `map` function works, but another alternative is to define `With` method on the type. This can take optional parameters for non-generic fields. For the generic field, you cannot quite do this (because it would unify the types), but you can have an overload:

```
type User<'TPhoto> = 
  { Name : string
    Photo : 'TPhoto }
  member x.With(photo, ?name) =
    { Name = defaultArg name x.Name; Photo = photo }
  member x.With(?name) =
    { Name = defaultArg name x.Name; Photo = x.Photo }
```

The first method is generic and returns `User` with a photo of another type. The second method does not change the photo and so it is non-generic. You can then use it like this:

```
let t = { Name = "Tomas"; Photo = 0 }

t.With(photo="img")   // Change type of photo
t.With(name="Tomáš")  // Change just the name
t.With(photo="img", name="Test") // Change everything
```